# How to use file creation date in old log file name when rolled over log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to have the creation date of the old log file in its filename, after a rollover. Currently the date in the log file name is not equal to the file's creation date.
As an example: if a log file was created yesterday and updated until today and is rolled over now, yesterday's date should be visible in old log file name.

log4j version is 2.14.1

log4j2.xml

```xml
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                     fileName="${sys:dir}/${sys:file}.log"
                     immediateFlush="true"
                     filePattern="${sys:dir}/${sys:file}.log.%d{yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss}.%i"
                     ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS} |%-5p| [%t] [%c] - %-100m %n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile> 
    </Appenders>
```

Log switch after the startup is done as follows inside the code

```
((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager().rollover();
```

This is similar to following bug but not fixed for OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
[File creationTime issue for RollingFileAppender, combined time/size policy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2610)

Comment: Do you use Log4j 1.2 or Log4j 2.x? Can you add the configuration of your rolling appender? There are many possible configurations and the filename of the old log depends on them.

Comment: log4j version is 2.14.1 and log4j2 configs updated in the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using OnStartupTriggeringPolicy, previousfiletime variable not updated with the creation of new file during a rollover. this is not a problem to the behaviour of the OnStartupTriggering strategy but current time printed on backed up log file during a manual rollover. This behaviour should be fixed in log4j but can do a workaround in application level to fix this issue as follows until the log4j issue is fixed.

```
  RollingFileManager rollingFileManager = ((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager();                
  long currentLogCreationTime = rollingFileManager.getFileTime();
  rollingFileManager.getPatternProcessor().setPrevFileTime(currentLogCreationTime);
  rollingFileManager.rollover();
```

Answer (score 1):

Which date is used for the rotated file greatly depends on the triggering policy:

- the [`SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html) and [`TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html) both update the [`prevFileTime`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/PatternProcessor.html#getPrevFileTime--), when they signal the need for a rollover. This happens before the rollover is performed, so the files end up with the date of the **current rollover**, not the previous one,
- the [`CronTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/CronTriggeringPolicy.html) never actually signals the need for a rollover (`isTriggeringEvent` always returns `false`), but performs the rollover itself using the date of the **previous rollover**.

Personally I find it a bit incoherent and in need of a major refactoring, but it is a complex mechanism and it is difficult to get it right. You should probably file a bug/wishlist report.

**TL;DR:** Use a `CronTriggeringPolicy`.